# JSON array into map with duplicate values

Tags: map, list, merge, array, duplicate-value

Final result when i tried the below code.

Answer (score 1):

If I have two `Map<String, List<Object>>` maps and I want to merge them, I **can't** just use:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> x = ...;
Map<String, List<Object>> y = ...;
Map<String, List<Object>> z = new Map<String, List<Object>>();

z.putAll(x);
z.putAll(y);
```

This won't merge lists from `x` with lists from `y` that have the same key value.

Instead I must do:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> x = ...;
Map<String, List<Object>> y = ...;

for (String key : x.keySet()) {
    List<Object> xList = x.get(key);
    List<Object> yList = y.get(key);

    if (yList == null && xList != null) {
        y.put(key, xList);
    } else if (xList != null) {
        yList.addAll(xList);
    }
}
```

This results in adding the lists from keys in `x` that don't exist in `y` and merging the lists for keys in `x` that also exist in `y`. Note that I don't bother with a separate map, `z`, because I'm literally merging the data from `x` into `y` for efficiency.

Comment: Hi @Phil W thanks for your reply. In my **LastMap** I got 20 keys with 29 values contains duplicate values. when I iterate with my LastMap.keyset() I get only 20 values instead of my 29 values  I am editing my current code in the question please check .

Comment: Apologize for my bad formatting . Kindly help me.

Comment: Also which List or Map will merge all my values into combined one.

Comment: Hi  I got serious trouble with the mapping I have tried your code but what I want is after hitting the first API 28 records need to be inserted with that matching 15 contact and 20 companies but the total needs to be 28 records final records instead i do get only 43 records since im passing companyId and contactId but i need only 28 records. How would i do that? i have my JSON response in the Questionnaire Section.

Comment: all my response i got only company id if i try to match with the companyId alone then ill get only 20 records as a result how to get 28 result with all fields mapping? I apologize i trouble you  alot but im literally hitting my head to find the answer.can you please help me @PhilW

Comment: It comes down to deciding which properties together represent your unique keys. I would ask you to update the question to explain how you know what the output should be for your inputs.

Comment: i have edited my code .please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you get a chance to see my question ?

Comment: @starboyThe see the comment I added on my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code will satisfy your requirement.

First, here's the POTATO class to receive JSON deserialized data:

```
public class ProjectRoleClass {
    public String PROJECTID;
    public String ROLE_NAME;
    public String CONTACTID;
    public String COMPANYID;
    public String POSITION;
    public String TELEPHONE;
    public String EMAIL;
    public String FIRST_NAME;
    public String MOBILE;
    public String COMPANY_NAME;
    public String ADDRESS;
    public String COUNTRY_NAME;
    public String STATE_NAME;
    public String TOWN;
    public String WEBSITE;

    public void doMerge(ProjectRoleClass other) {
        if (PROJECTID == null) { PROJECTID = other.PROJECTID; }
        if (ROLE_NAME == null) { ROLE_NAME = other.ROLE_NAME; }
        if (CONTACTID == null) { CONTACTID = other.CONTACTID; }
        if (COMPANYID == null) { COMPANYID = other.COMPANYID; }
        if (POSITION == null) { POSITION = other.POSITION; }
        if (TELEPHONE == null) { TELEPHONE = other.TELEPHONE; }
        if (EMAIL == null) { EMAIL = other.EMAIL; }
        if (FIRST_NAME == null) { FIRST_NAME = other.FIRST_NAME; }
        if (MOBILE == null) { MOBILE = other.MOBILE; }
        if (COMPANY_NAME == null) { COMPANY_NAME = other.COMPANY_NAME; }
        if (ADDRESS == null) { ADDRESS = other.ADDRESS; }
        if (COUNTRY_NAME == null) { COUNTRY_NAME = other.COUNTRY_NAME; }
        if (STATE_NAME == null) { STATE_NAME = other.STATE_NAME; }
        if (TOWN == null) { TOWN = other.TOWN; }
        if (WEBSITE == null) { WEBSITE = other.WEBSITE; }
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't used JSON2Apex for this. See also that I added `doMerge` that simply combines two instances of the class into one based on null or non-null values.

The two JSON responses (held here in the `firstData` and `secondData` strings, but obviously for you these would be loaded from callouts or whatever) are then processed and combined thus:

```
String firstData = '[ { "PROJECTID": 60030004, "COMPANYID": 2002004, "ROLE_NAME": "Consultant", "CONTACTID": 2965004 }, { "PROJECTID": 52445004, "COMPANYID": 2002004, "ROLE_NAME": "Engineer", "CONTACTID": 2965004 } ]';
String secondData = '[ { "COMPANYID": 2002004, "CONTACTID": 2965004, "FIRST_NAME": "Boult C.", "EMAIL": "testo@yahoo.com" }, { "COMPANYID": 2002004, "CONTACTID": 2969004, "FIRST_NAME": "Test C.", "EMAIL": "testo@yahoo.com" } ]';

List<ProjectRoleClass> projectRoles = (List<ProjectRoleClass>) JSON.deserialize(firstData, List<ProjectRoleClass>.class);
projectRoles.addAll((List<ProjectRoleClass>) JSON.deserialize(secondData, List<ProjectRoleClass>.class));

Map<Object[], ProjectRoleClass> projectRolesByKey = new Map<Object[], ProjectRoleClass>();

for (ProjectRoleClass projectRole : projectRoles) {
    Object[] key = new Object[] { projectRole.COMPANYID, projectRole.CONTACTID };
    
    ProjectRoleClass existingRole = projectRolesByKey.get(key);
    
    if (existingRole == null) {
        projectRolesByKey.put(key, projectRole);
    } else {
        existingRole.doMerge(projectRole);
    }
}

System.debug(JSON.serialize(projectRolesByKey.values()));
```

The important bits:

1. I assumed that two instances of the project role are equivalent if they have matching COMPANYID and CONTACTID, so used this combination as the key in the `projectRolesByKey` map
2. Project roles with matching COMPANYID and CONTACTID get merged together in that map if needed.

The result of the above code is (when formatted up):

```
[
  {
    "WEBSITE": null,
    "TOWN": null,
    "TELEPHONE": null,
    "STATE_NAME": null,
    "ROLE_NAME": "Consultant",
    "PROJECTID": "60030004",
    "POSITION": null,
    "MOBILE": null,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Boult C.",
    "EMAIL": "testo@yahoo.com",
    "COUNTRY_NAME": null,
    "CONTACTID": "2965004",
    "COMPANYID": "2002004",
    "COMPANY_NAME": null,
    "ADDRESS": null
  },
  {
    "WEBSITE": null,
    "TOWN": null,
    "TELEPHONE": null,
    "STATE_NAME": null,
    "ROLE_NAME": null,
    "PROJECTID": null,
    "POSITION": null,
    "MOBILE": null,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Test C.",
    "EMAIL": "testo@yahoo.com",
    "COUNTRY_NAME": null,
    "CONTACTID": "2969004",
    "COMPANYID": "2002004",
    "COMPANY_NAME": null,
    "ADDRESS": null
  }
]
```

I believe this is what you were looking for?

Comment: @starboyThe I strongly recommend you undertake the Salesforce trailheads to learn Apex. It will help you with this sort of thing.

Comment: yeah sure let me have a look . Thanks alot

Comment: You did notice the new answer as well, right?

Comment: Yeah @philw I’m working on it.

Comment: It is clear from the first callout that company ID is not unique - you have multiple project IDs for the same company ID. In the second callout you have people related to company IDs but not projects. In the last callout you have addresses for companies. What exactly do you expect to appear in the final array? The best I can suggest is a list of companies that have lists of projects and people. Otherwise you need to explain what you want in the output more clearly. What is the required resulting structure?